# PHP/MySQL foreign keys and displaying table

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables that reference each other.. Leagues, Teams, and Players.

Leagues have leagueid, leaguename, city
Teams have teamid, teamname, numberofplayers, leagueid(fk)
Players have playerid, playername, position, teamid(fk)

How can I display a table such as Players to show all of the contents and using the teamid foreign key, display their team name instead of that column?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Players.*, teamname
FROM Players JOIN Teams USING (teamid)
```

You just need to join on the `teamid` column that matches between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both tables use `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM   Players a
       INNER JOIN Teams b 
          ON a.teamid = b.teamid
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

By using inner join

```
    SELECT  b.teamname,a.playername, a.position
       FROM   Players a
         INNER JOIN Teams b 
            ON a.teamid = b.teamid
```

If you are specifying the league,

```
  SELECT c.leaguename, c.city ,d.* FROM
    (SELECT  b.teamname,a.playername, a.position
       FROM   Players a
         INNER JOIN Teams b 
            ON a.teamid = b.teamid) d
            INNER JOIN Leagues c
                ON d.leagueid= c.leagueid
```